# MongoDB: [ERROR]: Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:27017

Tags: java, mongodb, database

i'm trying to create a database for my mobile app which uses google cloud messaging. Anyways, i have MongoDB on my pc, but when i try to create it gives me "Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:27017. As i mentioned above.

Here is a ss: [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp8Uo.png)

thanks

Comment: Check for mongod process running on your pc

Comment: Nothing is running. I really need this, so please try to help me!

Comment: My skype - stail08. Fill free to contact if you need help

Answer (score 1):

You need to start mongod process on your ps - [Manage mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

Comment: you don't need to create db if you specified it in you app - mongo will automatically create it for you on the first insert operation